# How to do Integration tests NodeJS + Firebase Admin?

Tags: node.js, firebase, integration-testing, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to write some integration tests on NodeJS with Firebase (firebase-admin, with the test library jest and supertest), and some tests are failing randomly when I run all my tests. Separately, my tests are passing, but it seems like when too many test cases are running, some api calls are failing. Does someone here already had such problem? What are the solutions for this problem? What could cause this problem? (NB: I run my tests sequentially for not mixing up the initialization of my database. I use the option --runInBand with jest)

There are some mocking libraries available, but it seems like they work with the old api of firebase.

Another solution would be to mock all my functions that manipulate firebase, but I won't have a "real" integration test anymore, and it means doing a lot of extra coding for writing those mock. Is it a best practice to do so?

Thank you in advance!

---

EDIT: code snippet:

initTest.js:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const net = require('net');
const app = require('../src/server').default;

export const initServer = () => {
    const server = net.createServer(function(sock) {
      sock.end('Hello world\n');
    });
    return server
}

export const createAdminAndReturnToken = async (password) => {
    await request(app.callback())
        .post('/admin/users/sa')
        .set('auth','')
        .send({password});
    // user logs in
    const res = await request(app.callback())
        .post('/web/users/login')
        .set('auth','')
        .send({email:"sa@optimetriks.com",password})
    return res.body.data.token;
}
```

utils.ts:

```
import firestore from "../../src/tools/firestore/index";

export async function execOperations(operations,action,obj) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
      await Promise.all(operations)
        .then(() => {
          console.log(action+" "+obj+" in database");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log("Error", "error while "+action+"ing "+obj+" to database");
        });
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Error",
        "cannot execute this action outside from the test environment"
      );
    }
  }

  //////////////////////// Delete collections ////////////////////////

export async function deleteAllCollections() {
    const collections = ["clients", "web_users","clients_web_users","clients_app_users","app_users"];
    collections.forEach(collection => {
      deleteCollection(collection);
    });
  }

  export async function deleteCollection(collectionPath) {
    const batchSize = 10;
    var collectionRef = firestore.collection(collectionPath);
    var query = collectionRef.orderBy("__name__").limit(batchSize);

    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      deleteQueryBatch(firestore, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
    });
  }

 async function deleteQueryBatch(firestore, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) {
    query
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        // When there are no documents left, we are done
        if (snapshot.size == 0) {
          return 0;
        }

        // Delete documents in a batch
        var batch = firestore.batch();
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          batch.delete(doc.ref);
        });

        return batch.commit().then(() => {
          return snapshot.size;
        });
      })
      .then(numDeleted => {
        if (numDeleted === 0) {
          resolve();
          return;
        }

        // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
        // exploding the stack.
        process.nextTick(() => {
          deleteQueryBatch(firestore, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
        });
      })
      .catch(reject);
  }
```

populateClient.ts:

```
import firestore from "../../src/tools/firestore/index";
import {execOperations} from "./utils";
import { generateClientData } from "../factory/clientFactory";

jest.setTimeout(10000); // some actions here needs more than the standard 5s timeout of jest

// CLIENT
export async function addClient(client) {
    const clientData = await generateClientData(client);
    await firestore
        .collection("clients")
        .doc(clientData.id)
        .set(clientData)
}

export async function addClients(clientNb) {
  let operations = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < clientNb; i++) {
    const clientData = await generateClientData({});
    operations.push(
      await firestore
        .collection("clients")
        .doc(clientData.id)
        .set(clientData)
    );
  }
  await execOperations(operations,"add","client");
}
```

retrieveClient.ts:

```
import firestore from "../../src/tools/firestore/index";
import { resolveSnapshotData } from "../../src/tools/tools";

export async function getAllClients() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firestore
          .collection("clients")
          .get()
          .then(data => {
            resolveSnapshotData(data, resolve);
          })
          .catch(err => reject(err));
      });
}
```

clients.test.js:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../../src/server').default;
const {deleteAllCollections, deleteCollection} = require('../../../__utils__/populate/utils')
const {addClient} = require('../../../__utils__/populate/populateClient')
const {getAllClients} = require('../../../__utils__/retrieve/retrieveClient')
const {initServer,createAdminAndReturnToken} = require('../../../__utils__/initTest');
const faker = require('faker');

let token_admin;
let _server;
// for simplicity, we use the same password for every users
const password = "secretpassword";

beforeAll(async () => {
    _server = initServer(); // start
    await deleteAllCollections()
    // create a super admin, login and store the token
    token_admin = await createAdminAndReturnToken(password);
    _server.close();   // stop
})

afterAll(async () => {
    // remove the users created during the campaign
    _server = initServer(); // start
    await deleteAllCollections()
    _server.close();   // stop
})

describe('Manage client', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        _server = initServer(); // start
    })

    afterEach(async () => {
        await deleteCollection("clients")
        _server.close();   // stop
    })

    describe('Get All clients', () => {

        const exec = (token) => {
            return request(app.callback())
            .get('/clients')
            .set('auth',token)
        }

        it('should return a 200 when super admin provide the action', async () => {
            const res = await exec(token_admin);
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
        });

        it('should contain an empty array while no client registered', async () => {
            const res = await exec(token_admin);
            expect(res.body.data.clients).toEqual([]);
        });

        it('should contain an array with one item while a client is registered', async () => {
            // add a client
            const clientId = faker.random.uuid();
            await addClient({name:"client name",description:"client description",id:clientId})
            // call get clients and check the result
            const res = await exec(token_admin);
            expect(res.body.data.clients.length).toBe(1);
            expect(res.body.data.clients[0]).toHaveProperty('name','client name');
            expect(res.body.data.clients[0]).toHaveProperty('description','client description');
            expect(res.body.data.clients[0]).toHaveProperty('id',clientId);
        });
    })

    describe('Get client by ID', () => {

        const exec = (token,clientId) => {
            return request(app.callback())
            .get('/clients/' + clientId)
            .set('auth',token)
        }

        it('should return a 200 when super admin provide the action', async () => {
            const clientId = faker.random.uuid();
            await addClient({id:clientId})
            const res = await exec(token_admin,clientId);
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
        });

        it('should return a 404 when the client does not exist', async () => {
            const nonExistingClientId = faker.random.uuid();
            const res = await exec(token_admin,nonExistingClientId);
            expect(res.status).toBe(404);
        });
    })

    describe('Update client', () => {

        const exec = (token,clientId,client) => {
            return request(app.callback())
            .patch('/clients/' + clientId)
            .set('auth',token)
            .send(client);
        }

        const clientModified = {
            name:"name modified",
            description:"description modified",
            app_user_licenses: 15
        }

        it('should return a 200 when super admin provide the action', async () => {
            const clientId = faker.random.uuid();
            await addClient({id:clientId})
            const res = await exec(token_admin,clientId,clientModified);
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
            // check if the client id modified
            let clients = await getAllClients();
            expect(clients.length).toBe(1);
            expect(clients[0]).toHaveProperty('name',clientModified.name);
            expect(clients[0]).toHaveProperty('description',clientModified.description);
            expect(clients[0]).toHaveProperty('app_user_licenses',clientModified.app_user_licenses);
        });

        it('should return a 404 when the client does not exist', async () => {
            const nonExistingClientId = faker.random.uuid();
            const res = await exec(token_admin,nonExistingClientId,clientModified);
            expect(res.status).toBe(404);
        });
    })

    describe('Create client', () => {

        const exec = (token,client) => {
            return request(app.callback())
            .post('/clients')
            .set('auth',token)
            .send(client);
        }

        it('should return a 200 when super admin does the action', async () => {
            const res = await exec(token_admin,{name:"clientA",description:"description for clientA"});
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
        });

        it('list of clients should be appended when a new client is created', async () => {
            let clients = await getAllClients();
            expect(clients.length).toBe(0);
            const res = await exec(token_admin,{name:"clientA",description:"description for clientA"});
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
            clients = await getAllClients();
            expect(clients.length).toBe(1);
            expect(clients[0]).toHaveProperty('name','clientA');
            expect(clients[0]).toHaveProperty('description','description for clientA');
        });
    });

    describe('Delete client', () => {

        const exec = (token,clientId) => {
            return request(app.callback())
            .delete('/clients/'+ clientId)
            .set('auth',token);
        }

        it('should return a 200 when super admin does the action', async () => {
            const clientId = faker.random.uuid();
            await addClient({id:clientId})
            const res = await exec(token_admin,clientId);
            expect(res.status).toBe(200);
        });

        it('should return a 404 when trying to delete a non-existing id', async () => {
            const clientId = faker.random.uuid();
            const nonExistingId = faker.random.uuid();
            await addClient({id:clientId})
            const res = await exec(token_admin,nonExistingId);
            expect(res.status).toBe(404);
        });

        it('the client deleted should be removed from the list of clients', async () => {
            const clientIdToDelete = faker.random.uuid();
            const clientIdToRemain = faker.random.uuid();
            await addClient({id:clientIdToRemain})
            await addClient({id:clientIdToDelete})
            let clients = await getAllClients();
            expect(clients.length).toBe(2);
            await exec(token_admin,clientIdToDelete);
            clients = await getAllClients();
            expect(clients.length).toBe(1);
            expect(clients[0]).toHaveProperty('id',clientIdToRemain);
        });
    });
})
```

jest command: `jest --coverage --forceExit --runInBand --collectCoverageFrom=src/**/*ts`

Comment: We gotta see your tests and any corresponding code. As well as the commands you are using to run it

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: Not a part of the answer, but an npm package I would recommend for you. Here is how you can use it with webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias#usage-with-webpack

Comment: This doesn't work for you? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: I had a problem on the "deleteAllCollection" function, I forgot to put an "await".

Here is the correction for this function:

```
export async function deleteAllCollections() {
    const collections = ["clients", "web_users","clients_web_users","clients_app_users","app_users"];
    for (const collection of collections) {
      await deleteCollection(collection);
    };
  }
```